# Check if non-current user is logged in on a Zend Application project

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, zend-auth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check logged in online users using Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393760/how-to-check-logged-in-online-users-using-zend-framework)

I know how to check if the current user is logged in:

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance ()->hasIdentity ()
```

But how do I check if another user is logged in or not?

So if I wanted to check if user_id number 5 is logged in or not, does this have to be some kind of last logged in time check?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for specific users then you should store the login (session) data somewhere, so you can actually retrieve if specific users are logged in. Where you store it is up to you, but a database would seem like the logical choice.